# Network request failed when trying POST request in React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, http, fetch

I'm trying to POST request to my local server from my React native app, and get an error.

I built a general httpMethod function

```
export async function httpMethod(req) {
  try {
    var response = fetch(`${apiUrl}${req.api}`, {
      method: req.method,
      headers: req.headers
        ? req.headers
        : {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
      body: JSON.stringify(req.body)
    });
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

and I call it from this method:

```
export async function registerUser(props) {
  try {
    const { email, password } = props;
    let api = `/users`;
    return await httpMethod({
      method: 'POST',
      api,
      body: { email, password }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

the URL is `http://0.0.0.0:9000/users`

when trying to post this through postman, everything works fine:
[image]

after adding some console logs to make sure my HTTP request URL and params are fine I get this error:

```
HTTP POST  request to -- http://0.0.0.0:9000/users
 req.body: {"email":"Test@gmail.mmm","password":"@Aa123456"}    
 headers: undefined

Network request failed
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\core\whatwg-fetch.js:504:15 in XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror
- node_modules\event-target-shim\lib\event-target.js:172:38 in XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent
- ... 9 more stack frames from framework internals
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm thinking you need to define your request headers, it looks like you're defining headers as at least `content-type: application/json` in your code, but they're showing as `undefined` in your console logs.

Comment: try to use your Ip Address http://IP_ADDRESS:9000/users not http://0.0.0.0:9000/users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, the answer was embarrassing for me:

when running the app on my actual mobile phone the address "http://0.0.0.0:9000/users"

doesn't refer to the server's address, but the phone's address.

when running the request from an android emulator it worked fine,

and when running the same request to my live server's address it worked fine.